# How to hide all elements using jquery when the page is ready beside those that are in the visible viewport (screen) and show them back on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position

what i try to do is to hide all elements using jquery when the page is load/ready beside those that are in the visible viewport (screen).

then, when the user will start to scroll down and the element is in the visible viewport (user screen). elements will appear with fade effect.

so i try some combinations of code but none off them works 100%. need help to get this work without bugs.

here is first code i found on the web. it's seems work on the home page(front page) but when i go to iner page it does not work. and this code make some bug (slow the website).

the second code works good on specific elements. if i will change all specific elements and put only 'body *' it will make mess on the website.

the second problem is on scroll.
if some div or section have long content it will change the opacity back to 1 in the end of this div but its wrong! it need to change the opacity back when the top of the div is visible in viewport (user screen).

here is first code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Hide all elements outside the visible window */
    $('body *').each( function(){

        var top_of_object = $(this).position().top;
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window < top_of_object  ){

            $(this).addClass('hideme').css({'opacity':'0'});

        }

    });

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of the desired elements */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();


                if( bottom_of_window > ( bottom_of_object + 20 )  ){

                    $(this).removeClass('hideme').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

                }

        }); 

    });

});
```

this is the second code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
tiles = $("#sidebar1 .widget , article section").fadeTo(0, 0);
});
$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend sizzle to use own expression:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    inview: function (el) {
        var $e = $(el),
            $w = $(window),
            top = $e.offset().top,
            height = $e.outerHeight(true),
            windowTop = $w.scrollTop(),
            windowScroll = windowTop - height,
            windowHeight = windowTop + height + $w.height();
        return (top > windowScroll && top < windowHeight);
    }
});
```

Then, you could use it as:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     $('.hideme:inview').animate({opacity:1},500,function(){$(this).removeClass('hideme');});
});
```

PS: i didn't tested snippet...

Comment: Hello @AWolff, it help! but it seems it change back to opacity 1 before the user can see the animate.

Comment: @AWolff, thanks for help! but after i change to updated code there is long delay...

Answer (score 0):

Even when you set the opacity to zero the object still takes up space.  If you set  `$(this).addClass('hideme').css({'display':'none'});` then the object will not be rendered by the browser and will not affect the layout of your page.  The page will look the same as it would have if the element `this` had never been created.